# How should I implement currency conversion in my Druppal application?

Tags: drupal

If an User has X amount of credits on his account (I think CCK can store this value). He can create specific Nodes (requests for admin). Each Node has a Type (Taxonomy defined, may be. Or via CCK). Each Type has associated number of credits. When user publishes a Node providing certain type, his balance of credits decreases by the number of credits Node Type has (admin will perform this request and send user notification email).

This is some kind of very simple e-shop for activation codes. I didn't want to use Ubercart due to it's complexity. May be this functionality can be achieved using some simple Drupal modules? Or may be there are some alternate ways? Or it is better to go Ubercart (can it do what I want BTW)?

Comment: I really think that for something this complex and site-specific you're better off creating a custom module. (not posting this as an answer because I'm not quite sure the best way to store user credits as a module)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen folks in [the Ubercart forums](http://www.ubercart.org/search/apachesolr_search/points%20credits) do this kind of thing for purchasing/posting ads on a site.

Check out these modules:

http://drupal.org/project/uc_store_credit

http://drupal.org/project/userpoints_ubercart

Answer (score 1):

https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/taggartj/2343093

may be worth a look it is a credit system, adds a product feature to give user credits also has good helper functions to integrate with rules ect , also has a sub module to limit a content type by amount of credits and then deducts after the new node has  ben created & has blocks to show the user their credits and credit history :)